# How to make MDIForms in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I need to have multiple windows on main window. same as MDIForms. That means having parent and child relationship between main window and other windows.

But I am not getting how to implement this. can anyone help me for this...

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [Window Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/WinPanel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000031i)?

In essence, Apple's opinion of MDI is...

> "The MDI tendency directly contradicts
>   Mac OS X, in which windows are
>   document-centric rather than
>   application-centric. No parent
>   application "main window" exists--the
>   menubar and other interface elements,
>   like palettes, are used to constantly
>   indicate which application is active.
>   Document windows are only constrained
>   by the user's desktop size (which
>   might span single screen or multiple
>   monitors)."

Taken from Apple's [Switch to Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/ue/switch/windows.html) developer document (see the "Mac OS X Doesn't Use MDI" section). Whilst this is quite an old document, nothing has changed in this respect.

Comment: ya I read that.There is mentioned at most one window.tahts why i am putting my question here.

Comment: Precisely. As the guide implies, MDI in terms of windows "inside" a window doesn't exist as standard on Mac OS. (Applications like Photoshop are effectively going against the HIG by using such a notion.)

Comment: but we can use it in qt, why so? is there is any other alternative for this?

Comment: You need to accept the best answer (via the tick mark under the question's vote total) on questions which you believe to have been answered.

Comment: You can use MDI in Qt because Qt is designed for portability, not for adherence to any one platform's UI guidelines. This is one reason why Qt apps tend to be unpopular among Mac users who aren't also *nix users. They're like tourists reading from a translation dictionary, capable of being understood but clearly not natives.